# Show combined rows with common field

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a very large database containing our products and every product has several different variants. The structure of the table is like this:

```
id  |  Name  |  VariantName  |  dim1
 1  |  Smth  |  SmthCool     |  120
 2  |  Smth  |  SmthHot      |  160
 3  |  Smth  |  SmthRed      |  320
 4  |  Othr  |  OthrCool     |  220
 5  |  Othr  |  OthrBlue     |  128
```

etc...

Now, I'd like to be able to fetch the data based on the Name field, so that the output would be something like:

```
Name: Smth
Variant 1: SmthCool  Dimensions: 120
Variant 2: SmthHot   Dimensions: 160
Variant 3: SmthRed   Dimensions: 320
```

I currently have found a code that outputs all the entries based on the Name value, but I would need them combined like shown above.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT id, Name, VariantName, dim1
        FROM products
        WHERE VariantName="something"';

mysql_select_db('test');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "ID :{$row['id']}  <br> ".
     "Name: {$row['Name']} <br> ".
     "Variant name: {$row['VariantName']} <br> ".
     "Dimensions: {$row['dim1']} <br> ".
     "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: total noobs don't format tables like that.

Comment: Why do you use `mysql_` functions?

Comment: @buffjape: I'm a graphic designer, I know how to format code, but I never learnt enough to actually write it myself.

Comment: @trincot: because that's the only piece of code I managed to find online that does approximately what I need :)

Comment: You do realise those functions are deprecated for a long time now, have no support and have been removed from PHP 7. Don't write new code with that.

Comment: I see that fine answers get downvoted here, so I will move on. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunno why it was tagged with mysqli, but as you have to quit using mysql_* functions anyway, here is the solution that utilizes [one the best features of *PDO*](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#group):

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbname = 'test';
$dbpass = '';
$dbcharset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=$dbcharset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $opt);

$sql = 'SELECT Name, id, VariantName, dim1 FROM products WHERE VariantName=?';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(["something"]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

and here in the `$data` variable you will have a nested array grouped by name

```
<? foreach($data as $name => $products): ?>
    Name: <?=$name?><br>
    <? foreach($products as $row): ?>
        Variant <?=$row['id']?>: <?=$row['VariantName']?>  Dimensions: <?=$row['dim']?>
    <? endforeach ?>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Don't understand why this got down-voted. One should appreciate the use of PDO and FETCH_GROUP in this context. You got my vote.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly!
One more question: How much work would it take to make "something" a variable I can input in a text box? Would I have to use jQuery to make it work without refreshing/having two separate pages?

Comment: @SebastianPelan You'll have to use Javascript / Ajax if you need to make it work without refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

Well first things first, please do not use mysql functions they are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and totally removed from PHP 7. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

This being said, you are trying to fetch from the database the rows that correspond to name **Name** therefore your statement should be like this :

```
$name="Smth";
$sql = "SELECT id, Name, VariantName, dim1
       FROM products
       WHERE Name=".$name;
```

You can also use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to do the above.

And just before the loop :

```
echo "Name = ".$name."<br>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "Variant {$row['id']}: {$row['VariantName']}  Dimensions: {$row['dim1']};
}
```